# PDFBox fill template doesn't fill in auto calculated fields

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm having an interactive PDF with a couple of fields. When some of the fields are filled in the other ones are calculated. In Adobe Acrobat Reader this works fine.

Now when I fill in the document as follows:

```
public static void setField(PDDocument pdfDocument, String name, String value ) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    PDField field = acroForm.getField( name );
    if( field != null ) {
        field.setValue(value);
    }  else {
        System.err.println( "No field found with name:" + name );
    }
}
```

The fields are filled in but I have two problems:

1. For every field I get:

   May 04, 2021 11:57:04 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper getFormattedValue
   INFO: Field contains a formatting action but no ScriptingHandler has been supplied - formatted value might be incorrect
2. The fields that are normally auto calculated are not filled in. Do I need to trigger some actions or is it because the field is not formatted like a string or a number?

Comment: PDFBox doesn't support javascript. You need to format yourself, or implement the scripting handler interface and assign this. If not, the value will stay as it is. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4977

Comment: Thank you for your help. What about auto calculated values? Because when I fill in the pdf manually it calculates some values that I can't fill in because I don't see those fields.

Comment: That's because there's javascript in your PDF. Those invisible fields do exist, you can should use PDFDebugger (in "show internal structure" view) to find them. (Assuming you don't know where they are on the screen).